# Trying to retrieve channel from 802.11 frame with Scapy

Tags: python, wifi, scapy, ord

Currently I am working on some python code that iterates over all the available wifi channels and sniffs AP (beacon) probes and retrieves some information out of them.

For most probes my code works perfectly fine, it just filters out the SSID, BSSID and channel from the beacon.

```
def sniffAP(packet):
    if((packet.haslayer(Dot11Beacon))):
        try:
            ssid       = packet[Dot11Elt].info
            bssid      = packet[Dot11].addr3
            channel    = int(ord(packet[Dot11Elt:3].info))
            print("ssid: \t bssid \t channel")
            print(str(ssid) + str(bssid) + str(channel))
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
            return
```

However, with some probes I get an error: ord() expected a character, but string of length 4 found.
So, the problem that I am trying to solve here is that I want to successfully parse all the probes I receive. Does anyone maybe have some good (python Scapy) code for this? or suggestions on how to improve my code?

Thanks in advance,
Kasper

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed it. Now I use the RadioTap header to retrieve the channel info.

```
packet[RadioTap].Channel
```